# Angular Custom Directive template behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a problem with angular custom directives.

JS

```
app.directive('myElement', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
          item: '=i'
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        template: '<td>Name: {{ item.name }}</td> <td>Age: {{ item.age }}</td>'
    };
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table class="table table-hover" border=1>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
      <td my-element i="p"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This template is not rendering as 2 "TD" tags it is only rendering the "TD my-element" from the html with binded data inside.

If I change the template to

```
template: '<div>Name: {{ item.name }}</div> <div>Age: {{ item.age }}</div>'
```

The page renders with 2 div "DIV" inside the "TD my-element"

If I make replace=false everything goes away.

Why is the TD acting different than the DIV

http://jsbin.com/iMezAFa/168/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you have replace false, it puts the template inside the container element. You can't have two `<td>`s inside a `<td>`, that's just invalid markup. But you can have two `<divs>` inside a `<td>`.

Comment: Well my face is red.  Thanks, I had a thought about that at one point but got focused on the wrong part.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it as follow ..

```
template: '<table><tr><td>Name: {{ item.name }}</td> <td>Age: {{ item.age }}</td></tr></table>'
```

Comment: Yea, this would put an entire table inside the `<td>` which is weird and probably a lot less efficient than just using `<divs>` or something.

Comment: This moves the ng-repeat inside the template, which isn't really what I wanted.